# Set height to "the end of the window" for fixed div

Tags: html, css

I have `<div id="container">` that has `position: fixed; top: 106px; height:100%;` this causes this container to be out the screen 106px in the bottom of the window. How to set the height of that container to be "to the end of the window". ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bottom` property (<kbd>[see example](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/wh418dva/)</kbd>), i.e.:

```
#container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 106px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

... or, you can use the CSS3 `calc()` (<kbd>[see example](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/wh418dva/1/)</kbd>), i.e.:

```
#container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 106px;
    height: calc(100% - 106px);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: @Terry `bottom` does not work for me (maybe problem with a lot of other css on site). But `calc` works great! Thank you.

Comment: @rexilion That is strange, because the bottom property should work just the same way as the second solution... but glad that the `calc()` solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use calc() function.

```
 height: calc( 100% - 106px );
```

Compability: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use the calc option because of compatibility issues, try using

```
margin-top:-106px;
```